# Determinant gives two different value in two different methods

Tags: systems-of-equations, determinant

\begin{align*}
& \left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1-\lambda & -1 & 2\\ 2 & -2-\lambda & 4\\ 3 & -3 & 6-\lambda\end{array}\right|=0\\
\implies & \left| \begin{array}{ccc} -\lambda & -1 & 0\\ \lambda & -2-\lambda & -\lambda\\ 0& -3 & -\lambda\end{array}\right|=0 \qquad \text{Applying } C1=C1+C2, \& \; C3=C3+2C2\\
\implies & \lambda=0,0,2
\end{align*}
But $\lambda=2$ does not satisfies this equation.

If we expand determinant directly we get $\lambda=0,0,5$ and these satisfies the equation.

```
Anyone tell me where is my mistake?
```

**Updated:**. 
  \begin{align*}
& \left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1-\lambda & -1 & 2\\ 2 & -2-\lambda & 4\\ 3 & -3 & 6-\lambda\end{array}\right|=0\\
\implies & \left| \begin{array}{ccc} -\lambda & -1 & 0\\- \lambda & -2-\lambda & -2\lambda\\ 0& -3 & -\lambda\end{array}\right|=0 \qquad \text{Applying } C1=C1+C2, \& \; C3=C3+2C2\\
\implies & \lambda^2\left| \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 2+\lambda & 2\\ 0& 3 & 1\end{array}\right|=0\\
\implies & \lambda=0,0,5
\end{align*}

Comment: How did you go from the first equality to the second one?

Comment: What makes you say $\implies \lambda = 0,0,2$?

Comment: This looks like a very messy determinant to calculate from the beginning. Why don't you also try to change some of those annoying minus signs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the entry $\;2,3\;$ *after* you applied those elementary operations on the columns, it must be $\;-2\lambda\;$ , and also in $\;2,1\;$ it must be $\;\color{red}{-\lambda}\;$

Comment: Thank you for point out my mistake.

Comment: @PrimoRaj Also look what I added about entry $\;2,1\;$ ...!